# Expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray when sending image

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, chaquopy

I am trying to send a single frame from my client to the server via sockets. My code works when the path of the image is explicit. But, I am receiving an image as a string and decoding it. I'd like to send the image as a file to my server.

Here is the client code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from PIL import Image
import base64
import socket
import pickle
import struct
import io

def main(data):
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    client.connect(('192.168.0.14', 9999))
    BUFFER_SIZE = 4096*4

    decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)
    np_data = np.fromstring(decoded_data, np.uint8)
    img = cv2.imdecode(np_data, cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    with open(img, 'rb') as file:
        file_data = file.read(BUFFER_SIZE)

    while file_data:
        client.send(file_data)
        file_data = file.read(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

I am trying to pass the image as an argumento to open, however the image is not being returned. I am running a chaquopy script on java and the error given is:

```
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray
        at <python>.script.main
```

And the server that receives an image:

```
import socket
import time


date_string = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d-%H:%M")



server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(('192.168.0.14', 9999))

server.listen()

BUFFER_SIZE = 4096*4

while True:
    client_socket, _ = server.accept()
    
    
    with open('frames_saved/'+date_string+'.jpeg', 'wb') as file:
        recv_data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        while recv_data:
            file.write(recv_data)
            recv_data = client_socket.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
```

Comment: If you already have the image in memory, why are you trying to call `open()`?  `img` is certainly not a filename.

Comment: I wouldn't know how I could read the image being sent for as long as image chunks is being sent, using other approach. Basically, i was looking for the easiest  way to send the image by converting image to file, so I wouldn't have to worry about it. How can I send the image as image to the server, or read it as a file? I am not sure what to do here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `decoded_data` is already a complete image file, then I don't see why you need to use NumPy or OpenCV. Just send it to the socket directly:

```
decoded_data = base64.b64decode(data)
client.send(decoded_data)
```